# Does signal strength affect aircard bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, aircard

My boss has aircard service I think through verizon. It offers 188Kbps I believe. However, where he's trying to use it, he has one bar. Will this affect the bandwidth?

Comment: @Daisetsu These are two different questions. They happen to have arisen from one problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The lower the signal strength, the more dropped packets there will be.  These packets need to be resent, lowering the effective throughput.